# Prevent laravel morphMany casting id to integer

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Im developing an app, where the primary key of a Customers model is a brazilian document number, saved as string, with fixed length of 11 numbers. The customer has a MorphMany relationship to an "addressable" entity.

The problem is: when saving the address to the customer with doc number starting with 0 (zeros), they get dropped when the db casts it to integer.

For example: If the document number is `00012345678`, the value that gets saved is `12345678`

My question is: How to prevent addressable_id value of being cast from string to integer?

The closest solution I've got is to manually create the `addressable_id` and `addressable_type` in my `addresses` table. Would this be a good solution?

Comment: Is the length of the document number fixed? Like will it always be 11 digits with leading zeros to pad it?

Comment: yes... length is always 11

Comment: But only for the customer... other models can use normal integer ids...

Comment: I see, so using an accessor/mutator to pad the number with "0"s is not an option..

Comment: @AndersonIvanWitzke I'm not sure this will solve your issue, try to add `protected $keyType = 'string';` to the Customer model

Comment: Unfortunattely it did not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've got no other answers, I kept my own solution:

After looking at the source code of the [morphs](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2e6907851ae91685e4313b1258035bcc73bf1df1/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L1213) function I just manually added the columns and the index to my migration file:

```php
    $table->string("addressable_type"); // the owner class of the address
    $table->string("addressable_id"); // forces owner id to be string
    $table->index(["addressable_type", "addressable_id"], null); // creates index
```

So it does not matter if the id is the customer document number (string - like `00012345678`) or the id of another table (integer - like `0123` which will be cast to `123`)